# font-family not working in Firefox, but works in all other browsers?

Tags: css, font-family

I am using:
    body {
    font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    }

It shows the font correctly in Chrome, Safari, and Internet Explorer, but shows Times New Roman in Firefox. Am I missing something? I thought Franklin Gothic Demi was a built in web font...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the cache in Firefox.

Also consider embedding the fonts so that it is more compatible across all browsers and clients. http://www.google.com/webfonts

Some people discussed this exact problem.
http://forums.madcapsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=15267

Comment: I switched to Tahoma (temporarily) which works on all browsers. I may just keep it. By embedding, do you mean referencing one of those fonts as a @font-face?

Comment: Yes exactly. There are many free ones on Google Webfonts and my design partner uses it almost exclusively over the mass installed fonts. Droid is very good, for example.

Comment: OK I will have a look at that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Mac or Linux based operating systems, you can follow this:

1) go to https://fonts.google.com/ 
2)  **Download**  the fonts of your choice. 
3) Go to your **HOME** directory. 
4) Go to the **.fonts** folder (Create one, if it's not created before!) 
5) Extract the .ttf files from the downloaded zip folder (fonts.zip) into the .fonts folder. 
6) Use the appropriate CSS command with the fonts' family name and it shall work.

Tip: Google Fonts also provide you with the appropriate CSS line of code of the font family you are going to use!